# Java - Android trying to get my app to run on startup / unlock

Tags: java, android

I have an app and I would like it to run the second the device start. I did some digging online and found this code:

In my Manifest I added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

also in my Maifest I add this inside my application:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name=".Airport" android:label="Airport">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.airport" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And then I added this to my MainActivity.java inside the class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

but when I run in the emulator, it does run on start up. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I created an Activity called `StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver` and heres what it looks like:

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

but when I restart the android (unplug, plug back in) it does not start my application when it starts back up. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you then restart the emulator? `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` only happens when the *device* boots. Not when your app starts.

Comment: 1. You should add the onReceive in the StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver not in the MainActivity.2. You are starting a service by passing MainActivity. Also Can you try after removing the permission(android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)?

Comment: I have updated my question...I added a new activity to put the onReceive code in but it still does not run my application on startup.